# Is it not possible to show warnings when using mysqlimport?

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile, mysqlimport

This article: http://www.linuxask.com/questions/how-to-show-the-warnings-during-mysqlimport

says it is not possible to show warnings when using mysqlimport:

> When you use mysqlimport to import data from text file, the number of
>   warnings will be displayed at the end of import. But there is no way
>   to show the actual warnings message.

Is that accurate?  I have a server which does not allow LOAD DATA INFILE.

Comment: Do you have reason to believe it's not accurate?

Comment: No, none.  But I want very much for it to be inaccurate.  It seems a bit crazy that mysqlimport would show you that warnings were created but that there would be no way whatsoever to see what they were.

Comment: It's got a verbose mode and a debugging log - maybe one of those helps? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html

Comment: I've been using verbose.  I'll try the logging, thanks!

Comment: @Pekka웃 the debugging log with `--debug=filename.log` was not working, it looks like it is just enabled for debug builds: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=66854

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is - no you cannot output warnings from mysqlimport.

Answer (score 10):

I used the mysql CLI tool, passing an equivalent "LOAD DATA ..." command followed by a semicolon, followed by "SHOW WARNINGS". The resulting display is helpful in finding detail on each warning.

For example:

```
mysql <options> -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'foo' INTO TABLE bar; SHOW WARNINGS"
```